# Cómo hacer que muestre un 404 si la ruta o vista no existe

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

¿Qué tengo que modificar o agregar en `RouteConfig` para que si en la url digito o trato de navegar a una vista o ruta que no exista me muestre una vista 404 (añadida al proyecto)?

Archivo de rutas:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Trata de añadir algo más de información a la pregunta: ¿Qué te sale ahora con el código que compartes si la ruta/vista no existe? ¿Cómo tienes configurado el 404 que está añadido al proyecto? ¿Tienes definido el 404 en web.config?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si trato de navegar a algo que no existe me muestra "Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.", y lo segundo no lo se porque vengo empezando con esto, lo que quiero es que si navega a algo que no exista me muesdtra la vista 404 en lugar del "Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.", gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo logre añadiendo en el `Web.Config` la siguiente linea dentro de `<system.web></system.web>`

```
<customErrors mode="On">
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="NF/NF"/>
</customErrors>
```

La cual va rediriga a una vista con el error

Answer (score 1):

También podrias manejar el error NOT FOUND en Global.asax.cs como se muestra a continuación:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception lastErrorInfo = Server.GetLastError();
    Exception errorInfo = null;

    bool isNotFound = false;
    if (lastErrorInfo != null)
    {
        errorInfo = lastErrorInfo.GetBaseException();
        var error = errorInfo as HttpException;
        if (error != null)
            isNotFound = error.GetHttpCode() == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }
    if (isNotFound)
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("~/Error/NotFound");//lo que necesites
    }
}
```

espero te pueda ayudar